# Modifying text between a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to use getElementsByTagName and modify the text between a  tag before the script executes. For instance if the initial page contains the following:

```
<script>alert("original text");</script>
```

Is it possible to change it to

```
<script>alert("modified text");</script>
```

By targeting the  tag in the DOM

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
```

Comment: Why do that when you can just modify the function being called?  Why manipulate the DOM at all in this case?  Just set a variable with your string.

Comment: Sure, just step on `window.alert` and when it gets `"original text"` as a parameter, force it to call the original alert with `"modified text"`. (this is pretty tongue-in-cheek if you didn't realize)

Answer (score 1):

No.

In the absence of special cases like the `defer` attribute, inline scripts in `<script>` tags are executed immediately after they are parsed. By the time that another script can see them in the DOM, they've already been run.

Comment: That is what I assumed but I wanted to run it by the community for verification and/or possible hacks. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The script will be executed as soon as it's loaded and parsed into the document.

Any script that would try to alter it would either not find it because it's not parsed into the document yet, or find it after it already had executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but it's not quite what you are after.

Save the first into a script. And load the first in the header. Then once it is run, run this script:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName ( "script" );
var l = scripts.length;
for ( var i = 0; i < l; ++ i )
{
   if ( scripts [i].src = "myfile.js" )
   {
      scripts [i].parentNode.innerHTML = "<script>alert('modified text');</script>";
   }
}
```

But that would only change things AFTER.

To be honest, I don't see why you would want to do this anyway? Why not just call the one instead of the other?